# VSTO Outlook Add-in: Zip COM Object

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, gzip

I am trying to zip an email received before it gets attached to another email. So I am stuck with the zip part. The object that I am trying to zip is a COM Object and doesn't support serialization. Any ideas that can help me progress with this are welcome!

And the code so far (selObject is the COM Object):

```
private void Report_Malicious_Email_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    // selObject este mailul selectat
    Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
    if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem) // de aici incepe logica pentru forward cu atasament! 
    {
        using (MemoryStream msCompressed = new MemoryStream())
        using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(msCompressed, CompressionMode.Compress))
        using (MemoryStream msDecompressed = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(msDecompressed, selObject);
            byte[] byteArray = msDecompressed.ToArray();

            gZipStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            gZipStream.Close();
            msCompressed.ToArray();
        }

        Outlook.MailItem eMail = 
            (Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        eMail.Subject = subjectEmail;
        eMail.To = toEmail;
        eMail.Body = bodyEmail;
        eMail.Attachments.Add(selObject);
        eMail.Send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save message as an MSG file (MailItem.SaveAs(..., olMsg)), then zip the file.